# How to include an Excel formula with a reference to a table in Invantive Control Excel add-in

Tags: exact-online, invantive-sql, invantive-control

I'm making a financial report in Excel using the data from Exact Online using the Invantive Control Excel Add-in. In Exact Online I have a classification for the General Ledgers. In my Excel file, I would like to match these classifications on my reporting schedule. Therefore, I made a table with a mapping of the Exact Online classifications and the reporting classifications. 
Using the Invantive Control Excel add-in, I entered the following SQL query:

```
select periods_year_reportingyear_attr
,      reportingperiod_attr
,      division_code
,      division_hid
,      division_name
,      periods_year_years_balance_code_attr
,      periods_year_years_balance_description
,      '=I_EOL_GL_ACTCLN_CODE($C{E,.,.,^+2,.}, $C{E,.,.,^+5,.})' verdichting_code
,      '=I_EOL_GL_ACTCLN_DESCRIPTION($C{E,.,.,^+2,.}, $C{E,.,.,^+5,.})' verdichting_naam
,      '=i_eol_bal_year_open($C{E,.,.,^+2,.} , $C{E,.,.,^,.}, $C{E,.,.,^+5,.}) + if($C{E,.,.,^+1,.} = 1, 0, i_eol_bal_pder($C{E,.,.,^+2,.},$C{E,.,.,^,.},1,$C{E,.,.,^+1,.}-1,$C{E,.,.,^+5,.}))' startsaldo
,      balance
,      '=i_eol_bal_year_open($C{E,.,.,^+2,.} , $C{E,.,.,^,.}, $C{E,.,.,^+5,.}) + i_eol_bal_pder($C{E,.,.,^+2,.},$C{E,.,.,^,.},1,$C{E,.,.,^+1,.},$C{E,.,.,^+5,.})' eindsaldo
,      periods_year_years_balance_balancetype_attr
from   balancelinesperperiod 
order 
by     periods_year_reportingyear_attr
,      reportingperiod_attr
,      division_hid
,      periods_year_years_balance_code_attr
,      '=INDEX(tab_reporting[Reporting];MATCH(NUMBERVALUE($C{E,.,.,^+7,.});tab_reporting[GL Class - Code];0))'
```

In which tab_reporting is the name of a table with de mapping of the reporting classifications and the Exact Online. This table is on a different tab within Excel. I could send the Excel file upon request. 
This last line of the query results in the following error message:

[image]

> Syntax error between the two '***' on line 20, column 7:select periods_year_re...ance_code_attr, ***'=INDEX(tab_reporting[Reporting];MATCH(NUMBERVALUE($C{E,.,.,^+7,.});tab_reporting[GLClass - Code];0))'*** Error: no viable alternative at input '=INDEX(tab_reporting[Reporting];MATCH(NUMBERVALUE($C{E,.,.,^+7,.});tab_reporting[GLClass - Code];0))''

and in more detail:

```
itgensql056: Syntax error between the two '***' on line 20, column 7:select periods_year_re...ance_code_attr<LF>, ***'=INDEX(tab_reporting[Reporting];MATCH(NUMBERVALUE($C{E,.,.,^+7,.});tab_reporting[GL Class - Code];0))'***Error: no viable alternative at input ''=INDEX(tab_reporting[Reporting];MATCH(NUMBERVALUE($C{E,.,.,^+7,.});tab_reporting[GL Class - Code];0))''select periods_year_reportingyear_attr,      reportingperiod_attr,      division_code,      division_hid,      division_name,      periods_year_years_balance_code_attr,      periods_year_years_balance_description,      '=I_EOL_GL_ACTCLN_CODE($C{E,.,.,^+2,.}, $C{E,.,.,^+5,.})' verdichting_code,      '=I_EOL_GL_ACTCLN_DESCRIPTION($C{E,.,.,^+2,.}, $C{E,.,.,^+5,.})' verdichting_naam,      '=i_eol_bal_year_open($C{E,.,.,^+2,.} , $C{E,.,.,^,.}, $C{E,.,.,^+5,.}) + if($C{E,.,.,^+1,.} = 1, 0, i_eol_bal_pder($C{E,.,.,^+2,.},$C{E,.,.,^,.},1,$C{E,.,.,^+1,.}-1,$C{E,.,.,^+5,.}))' startsaldo,      balance,      '=i_eol_bal_year_open($C{E,.,.,^+2,.} , $C{E,.,.,^,.}, $C{E,.,.,^+5,.}) + i_eol_bal_pder($C{E,.,.,^+2,.},$C{E,.,.,^,.},1,$C{E,.,.,^+1,.},$C{E,.,.,^+5,.})' eindsaldo,      periods_year_years_balance_balancetype_attrfrom   balancelinesperperiod order by     periods_year_reportingyear_attr,      reportingperiod_attr,      division_hid,      periods_year_years_balance_code_attr,      '=INDEX(tab_reporting[Reporting];MATCH(NUMBERVALUE($C{E,.,.,^+7,.});tab_reporting[GL Class - Code];0))'Type: Invantive.Data.ValidationException   at Invantive.Data.ValidationException..ctor(String messageCode, String messageText, String kindRequest, String localStackTrace, String nk, Exception innerException)   at Invantive.Data.InvantiveParserErrorListener.SyntaxError(IRecognizer recognizer, IToken offendingSymbol, Int32 line, Int32 charPositionInLine, String msg, RecognitionException triggeringException)   at Antlr4.Runtime.ProxyErrorListener`1.SyntaxError(IRecognizer recognizer, Symbol offendingSymbol, Int32 line, Int32 charPositionInLine, String msg, RecognitionException e)   at Antlr4.Runtime.Parser.NotifyErrorListeners(IToken offendingToken, String msg, RecognitionException e)   at Antlr4.Runtime.DefaultErrorStrategy.NotifyErrorListeners(Parser recognizer, String message, RecognitionException e)   at Antlr4.Runtime.DefaultErrorStrategy.ReportNoViableAlternative(Parser recognizer, NoViableAltException e)   at Antlr4.Runtime.DefaultErrorStrategy.ReportError(Parser recognizer, RecognitionException e)   at Invantive.Sql.InvantiveSQLParser.column()   at Invantive.Sql.InvantiveSQLParser.sortedColumnList()   at Invantive.Sql.InvantiveSQLParser.sortedColumnList()   at Invantive.Sql.InvantiveSQLParser.sortedColumnList()   at Invantive.Sql.InvantiveSQLParser.sortedColumnList()   at Invantive.Sql.InvantiveSQLParser.sortedColumnList()   at Invantive.Sql.InvantiveSQLParser.orderBy()   at Invantive.Sql.InvantiveSQLParser.selectStatement()   at Invantive.Sql.InvantiveSQLParser.sqlStatement()   at Invantive.Sql.InvantiveSQLParser.sqlBatch()   at Invantive.Sql.SqlEngine.ParseStatement(String sqlStatement, Boolean allowSelect)   at Invantive.Sql.SqlEngine.Execute(IProviderManager manager, String sqlStatement, ParameterList parameters, Boolean allowSelect)   at Invantive.Sql.SqlEngine.ExecuteAndFetch(IProviderManager manager, String sqlStatement, ParameterList parameters, Boolean allowSelect)   at Invantive.Data.ConnectionManager.ExecuteProviderPassthroughSqlActionTable(String actionSql, ParameterList parameters, String& handlingPath)   at Invantive.Data.ConnectionManager.PassthroughSqlActionTable(String actionSql, ParameterList parameters)   at Invantive.Data.ActionProceduresBase.PassthroughSqlActionTable(String actionSql, ParameterList parameters)   at Invantive.Producer.Windows.Forms.FactsForm.SetDataSource(String sqlQuery, ParameterList parameters, String objectName)   at Invantive.Producer.Control.Editors.BlockFactsEdit.showFactsButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.LocalModalMessageLoop(Form form)   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.RunDialog(Form form)   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()   at Invantive.Producer.Control.Utility.OpenRepositoryEditor(Workbook workbook)   at Invantive.Producer.Control.ActionsRibbon.editModelButton_Click(Object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)   at Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonPropertyStorage.ControlActionRaise(IRibbonControl control)   at Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonPropertyStorage.ButtonClickCallback(RibbonComponentImpl component, Object[] args)   at Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonManagerImpl.Invoke(RibbonComponentCallback callback, Object[] args)   at Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)   at Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonManagerImpl.System.Reflection.IReflect.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] args, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParameters)   at Invantive.Data.InvantiveParserErrorListener.SyntaxError(IRecognizer recognizer, IToken offendingSymbol, Int32 line, Int32 charPositionInLine, String msg, RecognitionException triggeringException) in File104:line 122   at Antlr4.Runtime.ProxyErrorListener`1.SyntaxError(IRecognizer recognizer, Symbol offendingSymbol, Int32 line, Int32 charPositionInLine, String msg, RecognitionException e)   at Antlr4.Runtime.Parser.NotifyErrorListeners(IToken offendingToken, String msg, RecognitionException e)   at Antlr4.Runtime.DefaultErrorStrategy.NotifyErrorListeners(Parser recognizer, String message, RecognitionException e)   at Antlr4.Runtime.DefaultErrorStrategy.ReportNoViableAlternative(Parser recognizer, NoViableAltException e)   at Antlr4.Runtime.DefaultErrorStrategy.ReportError(Parser recognizer, RecognitionException e)   at Invantive.Sql.InvantiveSQLParser.column() in File59:line 1649   at Invantive.Sql.InvantiveSQLParser.sortedColumnList() in File59:line 1571   at Invantive.Sql.InvantiveSQLParser.sortedColumnList() in File59:line 1585   at Invantive.Sql.InvantiveSQLParser.sortedColumnList() in File59:line 1585   at Invantive.Sql.InvantiveSQLParser.sortedColumnList() in File59:line 1585   at Invantive.Sql.InvantiveSQLParser.sortedColumnList() in File59:line 1585   at Invantive.Sql.InvantiveSQLParser.orderBy() in File59:line 1398   at Invantive.Sql.InvantiveSQLParser.selectStatement() in File59:line 491   at Invantive.Sql.InvantiveSQLParser.sqlStatement() in File59:line 366   at Invantive.Sql.InvantiveSQLParser.sqlBatch() in File59:line 283   at Invantive.Sql.SqlEngine.ParseStatement(String sqlStatement, Boolean allowSelect) in File35:line 652   at Invantive.Sql.SqlEngine.Execute(IProviderManager manager, String sqlStatement, ParameterList parameters, Boolean allowSelect) in File35:line 552   at Invantive.Sql.SqlEngine.ExecuteAndFetch(IProviderManager manager, String sqlStatement, ParameterList parameters, Boolean allowSelect) in File35:line 513   at Invantive.Data.ConnectionManager.ExecuteProviderPassthroughSqlActionTable(String actionSql, ParameterList parameters, String& handlingPath) in File73:line 4499--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()   at Invantive.Data.ConnectionManager.ExecuteProviderPassthroughSqlActionTable(String actionSql, ParameterList parameters, String& handlingPath) in File73:line 4537   at Invantive.Data.ConnectionManager.PassthroughSqlActionTable(String actionSql, ParameterList parameters) in File73:line 2357--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()   at Invantive.Data.ConnectionManager.PassthroughSqlActionTable(String actionSql, ParameterList parameters) in File73:line 2369   at Invantive.Data.ActionProceduresBase.PassthroughSqlActionTable(String actionSql, ParameterList parameters) in File63:line 134   at Invantive.Producer.Windows.Forms.FactsForm.SetDataSource(String sqlQuery, ParameterList parameters, String objectName) in File604:line 82   at Invantive.Producer.Control.Editors.BlockFactsEdit.showFactsButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in File180:line 189Invantive Control for Excel (stable-20161021-2025-ge3e5e61 Prod, L162135034)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the `order by` part of your query. Invantive SQL currently only allows column names in the `order by` clause. Omitting the last line in the `order by` fixes the issue. You can sort on fields constructed in the `select` though, like `eindsaldo`.

I am not sure why you were trying to sort on a formule that doesn't exist in the actual select statement, it seems unnecessary to me.